# Bitbucket - Check the build status of a commit via REST API

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

### Setup

- I have a bitbucket repository that gets built by jenkins on every commit to the repository
- There is a merge checklist on the repository that disables merges until the build is completed
- I have a script, which automatically pushes updates to the repository and then issues pull requests and merges the pull requests.
- For the pull request and merge request I am using V1 of the bitbucket REST API. This is for legacy reasons. My bitbucket repository is running on my own server

### Problem

- Every time I issue a merge request it will fail unless the build is complete. Is there a way to check the build status via the rest API? The documentation for the REST API is not very clear, but I have not found a good way to do this. Has anyone else faced the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

For anyone that is interested, I ended up solving this by pinging the Jenkins server directly for the build status. This can be done with the following command

```
curl  -k https://{jenkins-hostname}/job/{job-name}/lastBuild/api/json --user {username}:{jenkins API token}
```

Note that the **{job-name}** parameter might be full job path. For example, my full request looks like this

```
curl  -k https://jenkins/job/Project-Folder/job/Project-Name/job/repository-name/job/branch-name/lastBuild/api/json --user {username}:{jenkins API token}
```